# When Should We Take Our Baby to the Dentist?

Tags: newborn

We've had several people provide us a schedule for our baby to visit a doctor, but nobody has given us specific information on when she should go to the dentist. Is there any standard recommendation for that?

EDIT: In regards to comments about asking my dentist directly, I'm more seeking if there's a standard consensus. The doctor schedule was pretty consistent: 2 days, 1 week, 1 month, 2 month, 6 month, etc. pretty much regardless of whom I asked. I'm curious if things are comparably similar for the dentist.

Comment: Have you asked your dentist to see what they recommend?

Comment: @Becuzz - I hate to be cynical, but... that's like asking the dentist if they would like more money to put their kids through college! (Isn't it? How many dentists will say, "oh, no, unless they have cavities, I don't want to see your child until their first permanent teeth come in."

Comment: @anongoodnurse Is that any different than asking a doctor how often you should bring your baby in to see them?  If we are OK with doctor's providing us information on how often we take our kids to see them, why shouldn't we trust dentists to do the same?

Comment: @Becuzz - I wish I possessed some your trust. Babies need to be seen to assess development milestones, state of nutrition, vaccinations, etc. We have good reasons for the schedules in place now. But specialists tend to do what they were trained to do. It happens with doctors, too. I fractured my wrist badly (like, in a *lot* of pieces.) Had I seen an orthopod, I'd have had plates and screws. I chose a specialty that does not tend to use plates and screws, and saved about $60,000 and all the risks of surgery. Do you have any idea how many kids get braces that don't need them? I could go on...

Comment: @anongoodnurse Well, if you have a doctor or dentist who isn't trustworthy, it's probably time to get a new one.  If I can't trust them, I don't want them messing with my body (or my kids).

Comment: I have no pediatric dentists in my area (rural) and the local dentists here are likely pretty old school I am guessing.  No one wanted to see my kids until 3 unless *I* saw any coloration issues on any teeth or if they were injured orally.  If I bring along a little one with an older child, they will generally ask if I want them to take a quick look in their mouth, but that is free & just a courtesy to get a professional glance and see if they note anything.

Comment: I should also say, *if * you have access to a pediatric dentist & have any reason to suspect your baby has lip or tongue ties then I'd take an infant in very young.  As it is here, mine is handled locally by an ENT, but in many places pediatric dentists are an option.  Correcting ties isn't just for easier breastfeeding, speech issues, etc, it can also lead to cavities in the front teeth along the gum line as it promotes food and drink to get caught there and not wiped away with free unrestricted oral movement. http://www.drghaheri.com/blog/2014/10/2/tongue-tie-and-lip-tie-faq

Comment: I noticed Dr Ghaheri's link expired on examples of dental caries caused by ties. Here is a working link to the same thing. https://www.borstvoeding.com/files/JHL2010_kotlow.pdf

Comment: @anongoodnurse Considering how many parents put their infants to bed with a bottle or give infants Coke - which is horrid for their baby teeth and their heath in general - I don't think it's bad for a parent to have an early consult with a dentist to discuss preventative stuff like that and to make sure that the parents aren't making "basic" errors.

Comment: @Catija - You're right about high-risk babies. But these same people (am I being terrible here?) should be following the advice - the same advice - that FP's and Peds have been giving for years. Will a dental visit - besides costing money - change that? So far, the only thing proven (that I know of) in studies of early exposure is that kids are less afraid of dentists. I may be wrong. But if the child's doc was doing their job properly, all this would have been covered repeatedly. Also, the decrease in the amount of dental caries in kids who do visit dentists may well be a selection bias.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is.

The [AAP (American Academy of Pediatrics) suggests](https://www.healthychildren.org/English/healthy-living/oral-health/Pages/Brushing-Up-on-Oral-Health-Never-Too-Early-to-Start.aspx) that your child see a pediatric dentist when the child reaches the age of one. This is because dental carries (cavities) is the most common disease in children.

The [AAFP (American Academy of Family Physicians)](http://www.aafp.org/test/fpcomp/FP-E_428/print_full_issue.html) also changed their policy in 2016 to recommend the first dental visit by 12 months.

I have not looked for the UK recommendation, but I suspect it's similar.

The pros:
- Kids who see a dentist from an early age are less likely to be frightened later.
- Kids who see a dentist from an early age are less likely to have dental caries in deciduous and permanent teeth.

The cons:
- It's expensive.
- Dentists take too many xrays of the mouth, increasing the risk of head and neck cancers significantly. The earlier the xrays, the greater the chance of developing a cancer over one's lifetime.

The only thing that has changed in recent years is that fluoride can be applied to teeth as a treatment now. Since dental carries in deciduous teeth can harm permanent teeth, this is recommended.

<sub>Note that what is recommended by pediatric dentists at the first dental visit is something that has been recommended in pediatrician's and FP's offices all along *except for the application of fluoride*:</sub>

> <sub>During the age 1 dental visit, there is strong emphasis on prevention and parents are given: (1) counseling on infant oral hygiene; (2) home and office-based fluoride therapies; (3) dietary counseling; and (4) information relative to oral habits and dental injury prevention.</sub>

<sub>[Examining the Cost-effectiveness of Early Dental Visits](http://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/aapd/pd/2006/00000028/00000002/art00003)</sub>
<sub>[Factors affecting dental fear in French children aged 5–12 years](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-263X.2010.01054.x/full)</sub>
<sub>[Dental x-rays and risk of meningioma](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cncr.26625/full)</sub>
<sub>[General info](http://www.aapd.org/media/policies_guidelines/g_fluoridetherapy.pdf) from the American Academy of Pediatric Dentistry</sub>

Comment: This seems very US focused - in the UK it is very different: no x-rays unless absolutely necessary, no incentive to sell (as all dental care is free for children) but I agree that early exposure to dentists is a good thing

Comment: @RoryAlsop - There is so much that is different in the UK. I wished to see many changes for the better in US medicine (all branches) under our former president, but... the US isn't ready for socialized medicine.

Comment: And we're going down the route of privatising all of ours :-(

Answer (score 3):

In the pediatric dental office I worked for (and I will mention that between the two dentists we had over 11,000 appointments per year), we recommended that children come in for their first visit about 6 months after their first teeth erupted - usually around 18 months - unless the parents had noticed something dentally that they were concerned about, in which case we would see patients earlier.

At that age, the emphasis is mostly on making sure parents know how to take care of their children's teeth, and what to do if the child sustains a traumatic injury to the teeth (as well as giving them someone to call if that happens - most dentists will not see a patient for the first time as an emergency, you already have to be an established patient). The other purpose is to acclimate the child to having their teeth examined, so they can learn that it isn't scary (and can be fun!)

At our office, we almost never did x-rays on patients under 4 or 5 years old unless there was a reason to do so (such as the child said they were experiencing pain, or the doctor saw something suspicious during the exam). We also did not do actual cleanings on children under 3 (just brushing). So the expense for a child that young should not be much - 2 visits per year at about $60-$70 each (at least until they're old enough for a cleaning). When children are old enough for fluoride/x-rays, the cost does go up significantly, but at least in our office we would only do x-rays once per year, and only billed for fluoride when we had not done x-rays. So it was still usually under $200 per visit.

I definitely think it is worthwhile to establish routine dental care as part of your child's expectations early on (my son loves going to the dentist and sometimes spontaneously asks to go), and it's also really important to have someone with whom your child is familiar (and vice versa) in the event of a dental emergency. That might partly be based on my own experience of not having had that - I fell and broke some teeth when I was a child, and because I had patchy dental care, it wasn't properly treated and developed into an infected maxilla which I then had to deal with long into adulthood. In terms of cost/benefit analysis, I'd say it's definitely worth it. But take the time to find someone you can trust to be good.